# Control Qwerty Dvorak Command Line

Tags: command-line, dvorak

Is there a way to remap all control keys while keeping the default locations which happen to be Dvorak locations on the command line?  This would basically be equivalent to "Dvorak Command Qwerty" on Mac.

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_character_representation.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850903/use-node-js-as-shell

Comment: @jsotola I updated my question.  This would basically be equivalent to Dvorak Command Qwerty on Mac.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want to keep `A` where it is but move `^A` over there? That's a non-starter. Read `man ascii`.

Comment: @waltinator yes essentially except a doesn’t move in Dvorak.

Comment: Impossible! `^A` or any other Control Character differs from `A` or any other Character only by having the `0x40` bit forced to `0`. It's done by the keyboard. Why, other than for a cruel joke, would you want to do this? I repeat `man ascii`.

Comment: And I thought my wife converting an actual typewriter from QWERTY to Dvorak was a strange thing to do.